# getMapBoundaries method is undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am using "react-native-maps": "^0.22.1" in my React Native Expo application. 


I am trying to use the getMapBoundaries() method in my code, but the method is not defined. Please note, I am for example able to use the animateToRegion() method.

```
  <MapView
    style={styles.mapView}
    ref={ref => {
      this.map = ref;
    }}
    onRegionChangeComplete={this.handleRegionChange}
    provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    showsUserLocation={true}
    showsCompass={true}
    showsScale={true}
    onMapReady={this.handleMapReady}
  >
  </MapView>
```

When I call the getMapBoundaries() method, I get an "is not a function" error.

```
this.map.getMapBoundaries()
```

Please let me know if you need additional information. 

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are calling `this.map.getMapBoundaries()` before your map is ready?
Try calling `this.map.getMapBoundaries()` inside `handleMapReady()`

Comment: Thank you for the response, I had tried that prior to asking the question. I have also tried using a setTimeout function to delay the execution of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [issue #2665](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2665), "the version that has this method is not published yet on npm, use the git version."